# How to find missing value from equation using java?

Tags: arithmetic-expressions

User made some calculations using program..and printed it on paper.. But mouse cut some part from the paper.

Now we have to create the program to find missing values.

Example:

```
54 + 27 = HOLE
3241 + 4HOLE45=7281
```

We have to find the missing value at `HOLE`.
If we pass multiple eqution at a time.

Comment: What is your attempt so far? Did you do the math?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You'll need to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The 2nd example does not make sense.

Comment: How are you representing this HOLE are you using any special character or dose the equations passed to the computer have "HOLES" typed in .

Comment: This sounds very much like a programming assignment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If (like in your example) the equations are separated by line breaks (or any other character will work) simply separate the equations maybe into custom objects then you can split each equations to numbers by splitting at every arithmetic symbols.

What I am suggesting is to phrase each line as an equation and find the missing bit by comparing both sides of the equal sign. You can find any one missing number each from any equation like this.

I have not provided any code example because you have not provided any code that you have currently tried out and also no specific language is specified. If you follow up with those I am ready to give a code sample.

Comment: I agree but when we have input like: 1234 + 3HOLE5 = 4669 .. Here HOLE=43... I am confused about this only.. I got your point by the way thanks.. But it would be great if you clarify me about this.

Comment: In this case you can break this equation into two equations as 305 + HOLE * 10 = 4669 - 1234. To do this you can check if a HOLE is followed and preceded by a number or white space. If it is a number convert it as show. This can be done fairly easily.

Comment: After this the new equation can be passed to the equation solver.